# Search and encrpyt single file in gpg encrypted folder

Tags: encryption, gnupg, tar, gzip

i have a huge gpg encrypted tar-gzip file ~100 GB. But only need a single folder from it.
I can list/search the content by doing eg.

```
gpg -d file.tar.gz.gpg|tar -tz |grep "filename"|more
```

This is super fast and i can quickly find the folder i need.

But if i try to decrypt this single folder it takes for ever (the file is on a network store :-/). I tried:

```
gpg -d file.tar.gz.gpg |tar -xz /path/to/filename
```

Could it be that tar must stream through the complete folder? Or is it not working with gzip / gpg compressed files?

**Update:** thx to Xen2050, i copied the wrong command line arugement here. Fixed it in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your examples use `-c`, decryption uses `-d`,  and probably need `--xz` for tar but that would mix formats & wouldn't work, but I'll assume they're just typos and you've got them working, but anyway...

You'll have to wait until gpg & tar go through the whole archive until hitting your target file, it could be near the start or end so may get lucky. Tar & gpg behave kind of like they're going through a tape archive, but instead of using `grep` you can see the files decrypted "live" by just outputting the file list to stdout.

Try getting a terminal on the local machine to speed things up, *if* the network is the bottleneck.

Comment: thx for your clearup. You are right i c/p the wrong command. Will fix it. thx for your explanation